# How to synchronize when read from main thread is completed after boost::asio::read_some is completed without polling?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost

```
#include <boost/asio/io_context.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/placeholders.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <queue>

class ClassA
{
public:
    bool _isok = false;
};
class Session
{
public:
    const char _buffer[1024];

    void SendHandler();
    void ReadHandler();
};


void Session::SendHandler()
{
    //do something (Send handler)
}

void Session::ReadHandler()
{
    // do something (Read handler)


    _socket->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(_buffer, 1024), Session::ReadHandler);
    //
}

int main(void)
{

    // Connect 
    // Assuming the connection is complete
    // ......connect.......
    // completed Connect and Init _socket;


    ClassA classA;


    //async Send
    boost::asio::async_write(_socket.,
        boost::asio::buffer(buffer, 1024),Session::SendHandler);

    memset(&_buffer, '\0', sizeof(_buffer));

    //async Read
    _socket->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(_buffer, 1024), Session::ReadHandler);

    
    // I wanna must do something( a = 1;) after finish ReadHandler() ( not using polling )

    if (classA._isok == true) //while(classA._isok == false){} (I don't wanna using this)
    {
        int a = 1; //after Readhandler  but I don't know what should I do not using infinity loop
    }
    
    
}
```

I wanna must run a=1;  on ensure 1 time after Readhandler
(_isok == true after Readhandler)

how to use synchrouse not using polling?
I wanna wait untill (_isok = true;)  ,not using polling

I don't want to run any subsequent lines until it is done by interrupt mode.

but I don't know best synchrouse way